# system.io.path says legal characters are illegal

Tags: .net, file, filenames

I am writing a util which deals with user archives and one of these test archives has a filename called `"".export`. In my code i loop through all the file extensions and i check for the file extension to ignore certain file types (such as thumb.db).

When i write `Path.GetExtension(v)` or `Path.GetFileName(v)` I get an exception with the message "Illegal characters in path." `"` is apparently illegal however on windows -edit nevermind it is illegal i originally thought the character was `'`) i can use that filename. Can i tell it to allow this character? Do i need to write my own GetExtension and GetFileName? What can i do?

Comment: " `"` is apparently illegal however on windows (and i believe linux) i can use that filename". Huh? It's illegal, you can't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't force a file system to accept characters that it doesn't want to. Windows just doesn't allow you to have quotes in filenames.

You'll need to either just strip the quotes (possibly replacing them with underscores or something similar) or work out some form of escaping for characters which are invalid in the file systems you're using.

Comment: Correct, i misread " as ' the first time so i thought it was legal when it in fact isnt. Thanks +1 and accept